# wire getPicklistValues User fields

Tags: lightning-web-components, custom-field

I am trying to use the 'getPicklistValues' in a lightning web component.

The goal is to get the picklist values of a custom field on 'User'. However to use the wire function you have to pass a recordTypeId, this doesn't seem possible, since Users don't have record types assigned to them. I am able to do this custom, but I was wondering if there's an option to do this with the default 'getPicklistValues' function.

Sample code for reference;

```
import { LightningElement, wire, api } from 'lwc';
import { getRecord } from 'lightning/uiRecordApi';
import { getPicklistValues } from 'lightning/uiObjectInfoApi';
import { getObjectInfo } from 'lightning/uiObjectInfoApi';

import USER_OBJECT from '@salesforce/schema/User';
import CUSTOM_FIELD from '@salesforce/schema/User.Custom_field__c';
import userId from '@salesforce/user/Id';

export default class UserCustomFieldSelect extends LightningElement {
@api uId = userId;

@wire(getObjectInfo, { objectApiName: USER_OBJECT})
objectInfo;

@wire(getPicklistValues, { recordTypeId: '$objectInfo.data.defaultRecordTypeId', fieldApiName: ACTIVE_OFFICE_FIELD})
customPicklistValues;

@wire(getRecord, { recordId: '$uId', fields: [CUSTOM_FIELD]})
user;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have missed one thing in your code syntax. i.e **'$objectInfo.defaultRecordTypeId'** will not give the default value but **'$objectInfo.data.defaultRecordTypeId'** will. You missed using data to get the defaultRecordTypeId.

A sample example to use the default record type for getting picklist value in Lightning web component.

```
import { getPicklistValues } from 'lightning/uiObjectInfoApi';
import { getObjectInfo } from 'lightning/uiObjectInfoApi';

@track objectInfo;

@wire(getObjectInfo, { objectApiName: CONTACT_OBJECT })
objectInfo;

@wire(getPicklistValues, {
   recordTypeId: '$objectInfo.data.defaultRecordTypeId',
   fieldApiName: GENDER_FIELD
})
genders;
```

**Update:-**

On User object, we don't have any master record type. I have confirmed it through below piece of code:-

```
Schema.DescribeSObjectResult dsr = User.SObjectType.getDescribe();
Schema.RecordTypeInfo defaultRecordType;
for(Schema.RecordTypeInfo rti : dsr.getRecordTypeInfos()) {
    if(rti.isDefaultRecordTypeMapping()) {
        defaultRecordType = rti;
        system.debug(defaultRecordType);
    }
}
```

This is the reason, you are getting the defaultRecordTypeId as undefined.

Comment: This was indeed missing, however defaultRecordTypeId for the user object still returns 'undefined'

Comment: @Kobe Please see the update.

Comment: Does this mean `getPicklistValues` is not supported for User fields, since there is no default record type?

Answer (score 0):

@Salesforce_Noobie getPicklistValues is supported for User fields, but you need to send a dummy recordtype id to

```
import { LightningElement,wire } from 'lwc';
import { getObjectInfo, getPicklistValues } from 'lightning/uiObjectInfoApi';
import USER_OBJECT from '@salesforce/schema/User';
import TESTPICKLIST_FIELD from '@salesforce/schema/User.StateCode';
export default class GetPicklistValuesOfField extends LightningElement {
    value ='';
    @wire(getObjectInfo, { objectApiName: USER_OBJECT })
    userMetadata;
    @wire(getPicklistValues,
        {
            recordTypeId: '012000000000000AAA', 
            fieldApiName: TESTPICKLIST_FIELD
        }
    )
    industryPicklist;
    handleChange(event) {
        this.value = event.detail.value;
    }
}
```